# Vert.x web streaming http-request body

Tags: vert.x

Is there any way to get the request body as a stream when using vert.x web?

I can only find getBody(), getBodyAsJson(), getBodyAsString() etc..
Under RoutingContext there is a HttpServerRequest which has bytesRead(). To me this indicates such a feature, but I simply can't find it.

```
    // Kotlin example
    val server = vertx.createHttpServer(serverOptions)
    val router = Router.router(vertx)
    router.post("/foo").handler { ctx ->
      ctx.getBodyAsStream()
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The body stream is the `HttpServerRequest` itself:

```
// Kotlin example
val server = vertx.createHttpServer(serverOptions)
val router = Router.router(vertx)
router.post("/foo").handler { ctx ->
  ctx.request() // HttpServerRequest is a ReadStream<Buffer>
}
```